# Windows - 'jupyter' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: command-line, jupyter-notebook

I'm on Windows command  line. 
I installed Jupyter via pip 3. 
I got this error, I suspect its path.

```
'jupyter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

However when I run

```
where jupyter
```

It returns:

```
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
```

Does this mean Jupyter hasn't downloaded properly? Because it seemed to be fine when using the pip3 command.

Comment: The issue was that my python environment variable wasn't being recognised on the path and so I edited the path to include python. Still unsure as to why it wasn't being recognised though.

Answer (score 8):

Use the command `py -m notebook` and the problem is sloved.

Answer (score 2):

When you are installing Anaconda ensure to check the check boxes to add the path to env. This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

It could have two reasons:

## Either Anaconda is not installed in Windows.

- Install it.

## Path for Anaconda is not set in Environment variable.

Open Anaconda Command Prompt, search for "`where conda"`.

Results:

```
C:\Users\<loremipsm>\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\Library\bin\conda.bat
C:\Users\<loremipsum>\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\Scripts\conda.exe
```

Use : Path as `"C:\Users\<loremipsum>\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\Scripts"`

**Path is a sample one, use you own.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also new to Python, but this is what I found.

Try installing using Anaconda, check **Add Anaconda to my PATH environment variable**.

The reason is because if it's not checked, or if you use pip 3, paths are not automatically added.

You may also choose to manually add the path in Setting - Environment Variables.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add path,where Anaconda is installed,in the Environment variable.
In my case it's
C:\Users\zahid\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Library\bin
C:\Users\zahid\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts

Answer (score 0):

Even I was stucked with the same issue.

What I did was I searched for the jupyter path in the Anaconda Prompt using the command "where jupyter"

After that I got a path

Then I went to my Environment variables(you would get this thing when you would search for the same) and then specified the new path there.
And the problem was solved.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This question already has several answers with good examples and description. And you had slightly different issue(i.e. where yielded path for you but did not for OP). If you think that your answer can be better than others then please add extra explanation and examples

Answer (score 0):

Go to start and search for Anaconda Navigator

Launch the program

Then in Home section you will see Jupyter Notebook then click on Launch

Hope this helps